# ST_UNION if buffered polygons overlaps or intersects

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to `ST_UNION` buffered polygons through the following line of code

`select ST_DUMP(ST_UNION(ST_TRANSFORM(ST_BUFFER(the_geom::geography, 100,'endcap=square')::geometry, 3857))) from table`

at `ST_Transform` everything it's okay, I obtain the buffered area but then I try to "JOIN INTO ONE POLYGON" only the ST_BUFFER polygons that intersects with other and the result it's an "UNKNOW" column

[image]

Is there any other way to achive this? Or do I have to cast the results to obtain a correct geometry

Comment: `ST_Dump` returns (a set of a) [*composite type*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html), specifically a [`geometry_dump`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_dump.html) - you will have to access the `geom` field in order to use it. Post your findings after doing so if the geometry is not what you expected.

Comment: As geozelot said, you need to access the geom. You can do `(ST_Dump(...)).geom` to do so

Comment: gentleman's did it work, the 2 buffered polygons that intersect between them now are a single polygon. now that my original data was transformed into a geometry dump, took me to read the documentation you left for me and help me to understand how the buffer method work and the result data